# webpush not wokring in chrome on localhost

Tags: node.js, web-push

I'm building a website with node.js and I' m making some push notifications and it doesn' t send them on chrome version 109.0.5414.120 . I tried running it on opera gx and it worked there. I have to use chrome because its for a school project and all my teachers use chrome and the don't want to download new programms

the code;
`app.js`

```
const express = require("express")
const webpush = require('web-push')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json());

const path = require("path")
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))

const publicKey = "BL2QpTNn-CZARUqJhm4tDPPful3TMIjugZdyi1WNIcaps21w7KJFy4cjilMNk-NbeEIwWVA5ddCXpOStd6RTuXA"
const privateKey = "dWcFCcnNS-uBYS6GISodobLXht-9KpOQmeHh1h89T7w"

webpush.setVapidDetails("mailto:thdegroote18@gmail.com", publicKey, privateKey)

app.post("/subscribe", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Subscription Details From the client side , We would get back to this
        const subscription = req.body;
        subscribers.push(subscription);

        // Save the new subscrber to the subscribers file
        fs.writeFileSync("./subscribers.json", JSON.stringify(subscribers));

        res.status(201).send("Subscription Saved");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

const subscribers = require("./subscribers.json")
const fs = require("fs")
async  function sendPushNotificaiton() {
    for (let i = 0; i < subscribers.length; i++) {
        const subscription = subscribers[i];
        //Notification Payload, this could contain more information about the notification
        const payload = {
            title: "Push Test", 
            body: " Push Notification Message",
            icon: "https://blog.mensaiah.com/assets/round_logo.png",
        };

        //Pass object into sendNotification
        await webpush.sendNotification(subscription, JSON.stringify(payload));
    }

}

//Send Notification Every Minute
const durationInMillisecond  = 60 * 10000
setInterval(sendPushNotificaiton,durationInMillisecond);

const port = 1999

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server started on port ${port}`)
})
```

`client.js`

```
const publicVapidKey = "BL2QpTNn-CZARUqJhm4tDPPful3TMIjugZdyi1WNIcaps21w7KJFy4cjilMNk-NbeEIwWVA5ddCXpOStd6RTuXA";

async function subscribeToPush() {
    console.log("Registering service worker...");
    const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/worker.js", {
        scope: "/"
    });
    console.log("Service Worker Registered...");

    console.log("Registering Push...");
    const subscription = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
    });
    console.log("Push Registered...");

    console.log("Subscribing for Push ...");
    await fetch("http://localhost:1999/subscribe", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    });
}



function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    const padding = "=".repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding)
        .replace(/\-/g, "+")
        .replace(/_/g, "/");

    const rawData = window.atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
        outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return outputArray;
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    subscribeToPush().catch(console.log);
}
```

`worker.js`

```
self.addEventListener("push", e => {

    // Data from service
    const data = e.data.json();
    console.log("Push Recieved...");
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
        body: data.body,
        icon: data.icon,
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Also I'm wondering why you are using urlBase64ToUint8Array function since the value is just a string